# How do I send additional params with an ajax fileupload?

Tags: ajax, html, file, upload

I'm using the html5 canvas to drag and drop file uploads but I need to send additional info with the dropped files.  specifically a recordID.   I'm sending my file to php like this :

```
canvasData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", './php/uploadImage.php', false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(canvasData);
```

How do I add an additional param of recordID = recordID along with the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can send it as a URL query parameter:

```
ajax.open('POST', './php/uploadImage.php?recordID' + recordID, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with

```
ajax.open("POST", './php/uploadImage.php?recordID=' + recordID, false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send('recordID='+recordID+'&'+canvasData);
```